# Noncausal dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems, systems-theory

The differential equation
$$a_ny(t)^{(n)} + \dots + a_0y(t)^{(0)} = b_mu(t)^{(m)} + \dots + b_0u(t)^{(0)} $$
with $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y,u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ describes a time-independent, linear, SISO system.

Why is this system noncausal (that means not physically realizable) if $m > n$?

---

For instance, this equation describes a noncausal system ($n = 0, m = 1$):
$$y(t) = u'(t)$$
and using the definition of the derivative it becomes
$$y(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\Delta t}$$
This means that the output signal at time $t$ depends from a future input signal value $u(t + \Delta t)$ and it makes sense to me that this system is not realizable.

But why this other system is realizable ($n = 1, m = 1$)?

$$y(t) = u'(t) + y'(t)\\\iff$$
$$y(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\Delta t} + \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{y(t + \Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t} $$

$y(t)$ depends from a future input signal value too.

Comment: did you got the answer? I'm stuck with exactly the same doubt!

Comment: I get it just right now :) Thanks to @arthur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ u'(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\Delta t}$$

Use this forward difference recursively to write $u^{(2)}(t)$

$$ u^{(2)}(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{u'(t + \Delta t) - u'(t)}{\Delta t} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \left[ \frac{\frac{u(t + 2\Delta t) - u(t+ \Delta t)}{\Delta t} - \frac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\Delta t}}{\Delta t} \right]$$

$$ u^{(2)}(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \left[  \frac{u(t + 2\Delta t) - u(t+ \Delta t)}{\Delta t^2} - \frac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\Delta t^2} \right]$$

For the $u^{(m)}(t)$  derivative the leading term is $u(t+m \Delta t)$ and for $y^{(n)}(t)$ it is $y(t+n \Delta t)$.

If $m > n$ then the forward difference discrete model of the system is non causal.

A backward difference exists where:

$$ u'(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{u(t) - u(t -  \Delta t)}{\Delta t}$$

I've only ever used the backward difference in real world software.

Comment: mhh, I can glimpse the point! So, roughly speaking, greater order of derivative means greater future knowledge, isn't it?

Comment: Surfer on the fall - Yes. If you use the backward difference you need more points from the past.

Comment: Zero derivative (value of the function in the point) gives you a strictly local piece of information, first derivative (increase/decrease) gives you a bit more of general insight and so on with the second derivative (convexity/concavity).. when talking about systems, greater generality (less locality) has to be seen as greater future/past knowledge...Do you agree with this interpretation of your calculus? Thanks a lot for the precious help!

Comment: Surfer on the fall - You're welcome. I focused on control theory at university and think of differential equations and discrete time systems (Z transform) in the terms I was taught. System/Model/Controller/Estimator in a feedback loop.
You can't know the future value but you can estimate it and use it in the controller.  PID controllers have a long history and are very common in industry. They use Proportional (linear) , Integral and Differential values of the input to control processes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller